# How to transform a flat map to complex JSONObject?

Tags: java, json

I want to transform a flat key-value map into a complex json object.

Structure is as follows:

- the map-keys of course represent the json keys.
- nested elements are separated by a dot
- list elements are signaled by a digit at the end of the key. there may be multiple digits at the end. The keys unfortunately stand in reversed order. Mean that the first "key-fragment" maps to the last digit, and the innermost key-fragment maps to the first digit.

Following example:

```
service.fee.1.1=a
service.fee.2.1=b
service.fee.3.1=c
```

Here the "service" key maps always to index=1. This means "service" is an array, but with only one element in this case.
The one element has the key "fee", with 3 values inside.

The resulting `json` should thus be:

```
{
    "service": [
        {
            "fee": ["a", "b", "c"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Another example:

```
service.fee.name.1.1=a
service.fee.age.2.1=b
service.fee.test.2.1=c

{
    "service": [
        {
            "fee": [
                {
                    "name": "a"
                },
                {
                    "age": "b",
                    "test": "c"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

That's what I started with, but I cannot get the point where I probably have to use recursion to handle nested objects and lists:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    if (endswithdigit(key)) {

    } else {
        if (key.contains("-")) {
            //complex object
            JSONObject subjson = new JSONObject();
            json.put(key, subjson);

            //TODO probably have to apply some kind of recursion here with subjson??
        } else {
            //plain value
            json.put(key, entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe you could give advise how to properly build a nested `JSONObject` with nested lists and recursion?

Comment: Why are the list indexes inverted? Isn't that more complicated to work with? Also checkout Gson library which makes very easy to map back and forth json object and java objects.

Comment: Because I'm not in control of the source key-value maps. I get them and want to process them. I do not want to map them to predefined java beans/models with `gson`, because the input in the key-value maps can vary. I just want to transform them to `json` format with above rules. This the gson-lib is not of help here.

Comment: OP Are you absolutely certain the indexes to the arrays are inverted and you have not made a mistake in your question.

Comment: Absolutely. That's also the main reason I cannot get my head around how to "reverse-iterate" that properly...

Comment: Also why do you have the property name "test" in your second output example. Where does that come from? Why not just have string primitives in your array?

Comment: There's ambiguity in this question.  Is there any reason that the outer tags (eg. "service") is an array, despite containing a single object within that array?  Why are there three separate "test" objects in the second example but only one "fee" array in the first?  Is it possible to have differing levels of digits (IE: one entry with a 3-digit index, and another with a 2-digit), and what is the intended behavior in such a case?

Comment: @membersound if it were me I would first preprocess the inputs to to put the indexes in a sensible order.

Comment: @Ironcache I rewrote the 2nd example a bit to make it more clear.

Comment: What about the differing index levels?  Is it legal to have `x.y.2.1` and `x.y.2.1.1` in the same map?  And what is the intention if so? `1.1.2` comes before `1.2` (considering the indices in "proper" position)?

Comment: Also in your edited second example, what is causing `age` and `test` to get associated with the same position in the `fee` array, versus having their own arrays with an entry at `1.2` (again, reversing the index for clarity)?

Comment: There may not be more indexes than key-levels. So `x.y.2.1.1` would be invalid. Regarding `fee.age` and `fee.test`: both belongs to the 1st `service` key. and both belong to the 2nd `fee` key. That's what `*.2.1` stands for.

Comment: Okay, I think it's becoming more clear.  So does `x.y.z.2.1=a` say "in position `1` of `x`, there exists `y`.  In position `2` of that `y`, there exists `z`.  The value of that `z` is `'a'`."?  **EDIT**: your edit to the above comment makes it clear.

Comment: What is the intention if there is a gap in elements?  IE: `x.y.z.3.1` and `x.y.z.1.1` but no `x.y.z.2.1`?

Comment: Also is it possible to have both `x.y.1.1` (as in your first example) and `x.y.z.1.1` (as in your second example), and what is the intended behavior?  Both a non-object array value and an object cannot occupy the same `1.1` index.

Comment: Both can happen, and is decided upon the first element. It is guaranteed not both happens in the same file at once. Gaps in elements would occur if eg the elements represent lines of text. Then the gap stands for an empty line.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to tackle this problem yourself (IE: a library cannot handle it), then I would break it down so that it can be coherently tackled with [Composite Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

I'll address this answer in two parts: first, a proposed solution to create the heirarchy; and second, how to utilize the Composite pattern to turn your internal heirarchy into the JSON you want.

---

**Part 1: Creating the Heirarhcy**

One approach for this would be to iteratively create objects by dividing elements in to bins (starting with a common composite root object that contains every element).  This will form the composite structure of your data.  The flow will be:

- For each element in the bin of the object composite:

  - Strip off the top-level identifier from the left of the element
  - Create an identifier to be associated with it.
  - If it is keyed:

    - Strip off the key from the right
    - Create a composite array for the identifier (if it does not exist).
    - If there is further data left of the `=` of the element:

      - Create a composite object for the element bin associated with that array index (if it does not exist).
      - Place the element in a bin for that object.
    - Otherwise create a leaf node for the value of the index.
  - Otherwise, if there is further data left of the `=` of the element:

    - Create a composite object for the element bin associated with that array index (if it does not exist).
    - Place the element in a bin for that object.
  - Otherwise, create a leaf node for the value of the identifier.
- Repeat for all new bins.

For example's sake, lets assume we are working with the given dataset:

```
x.y.z.1.1=A
x.y.z.3.1=B
x.y.w.1.1=C
x.u.1=D
a.b.1=E
a.c.1=F
e.1=G
e.2=H
i=I
m.j=J
m.k=K
```

The process would then follow as:

```
ITERATION 0 (initialize):
root // x.y.z.1.1=A, x.y.z.3.1=B, x.y.w.1.1=C, x.u.1=D, a.b.1=E, a.c.1=F, e.1=G, e.2=H, i=I, m.j=J, m.k=K

ITERATION 1:
root :
  x[1] // y.z.1=A, y.z.3=B, y.w.1=C, u=D
  a[1] // b=E, c=F
  e[1] : "G"
  e[2] : "H"
  i : "I"
  m : // j=J, k=K

ITERATION 2:
root :
  x[1] : 
    y[1] // z=A, w=C
    y[3] // z=B
    u : "D"
  a[1] :
    b : "E"
    c : "F"
  e[1] : "G"
  e[2] : "H"
  i : "I"
  m : 
    j : "J"
    k : "K"

ITERATION 3:
root :
  x[1] :
    y[1] :
      z : "A"
      w : "C"
    y[3] :
      z : "B"
    u: "D"
  a[1] :
    b : "E"
    c : "F"
  e[1] : "G"
  e[2] : "H"
  i : "I"
  m : 
    j : "J"
    k : "K"
```

---

**Part 2: Composite Pattern**

At this point, we've iteratively divided our data into a heirarchical composite structure; now we just need to get our internalized data structure into JSON.  This is where the Composite pattern will come in handy; each of your objects will implement the following interface:

```
// All objects in the composite tree must implement this.
public interface Jsonable {
    // The non-leaf objects will need to have their implementation of this
    // call it for each child object (and handle gaps).
    JsonObject toJsonObject(); 
}
```

If following the above, we would likely have three implementations of this interface: `ArrayComposite`, `ObjectComposite`, and `ValueLeaf`.

Calling `toJsonObject()` on your root element will give you your complete `JsonObject`.  A textural representation of that for the above example is below (notice the added gap in the `y` array; this needs to be handled in the `toJsonObject()` call of your array composites):

```
{
  "x" : [
    {
      "y" : [
        {
          "z" : "A",
          "w" : "C"
        },
        "",
        {
          "z" : "B"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "a" : [
    {
      "b" : "D",
      "c" : "E"
    }
  ],
  "e" : [
    "F",
    "G"
  ]
  "i" : "I"
  "m" : {
    "j" : "J",
    "k" : "K"
  }
}
```

Which, neglecting white spacing, seems to be what you're looking for.

---

Note that this assumes a data set does not contain elements that would result in invalid JSON.  IE: the dataset could not contain the following:

```
i=I
i.1=I
```

As it would be saying that `i` is both an array and a value.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the Gson library and use new Gson().toJson(yourmap); this will convert your map to JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you resolve it by splitting the key where the numbers start, and using a LIFO for the subkeys and a FIFO for the value and indexes. Instead for splitting it can be done by parsing the key and detecting where the numbers start:

For example:

```
x.y.z.2.1 = val
```

This is split to show how it would work, but it can be done just parsing the string (: is to delimit the separation).

```
x.y.z : 2.1 : val
```

Then put the subkeys in a LIFO (x goes in first, z last):

```
LIFO
head: z
      y
      x
```

and a FIFO for the value and indexes (2 goes in first, val goes last)

```
Fifo
top:2
    1
    val
```

Then you can pop out from the LIFO and match it to the pop of the FIFO. The first assignment will be for the value of the map, then, the assignments will be done to the object or array of the last step.

```
z = val
y[1] = z
x[2] = y
```